# Flutter Stripe Currency Change

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I've been trying everything but cant figure out that how can I change the payment currency of Stripe embedded in my Flutter App, I don't have any problems receiving the payment on USD but I want the Stripe Popup to show PKR instead of USD. Is there any way that I can Force code it to show or some other way?

I've tried to change it on my stripe account but cant find anything other than giving a specific customer a different currency.

Answer (score 1):

The supported currencies on your account are mostly based on where your account is located. If your account is based in the US then thats the currency that your funds will settle in. You can check what currencies are supported based on your account's location here [1].

If you want to charge your users in a different currency then you'd want to modify the integration to set the currency accordingly. For example, if you're using PaymentIntents API to create charges then you'd set the `currency` property [2] according to your preference (given it is supported). The funds will then be converted in your settlement currency. More information here [3]

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#presentment-currencies

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-currency

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/currencies/conversions

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKV9q.png

I have added the currency property in the paymentIntent API but the currency is not changing anywhere from usd